# $E \subset X$ and $\mu ^* (E)=0$, then $E$ is $\mu^*$measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure

Let $\mu^*: P(X) \rightarrow [0, +\infty]$ be an outer measure and $E \subseteq X$such that $\mu^*(E)=0$. I want to show that $E$ is $\mu^*$measurable.

For this we have to show that:
$$\mu^*(A)=\mu^*(A \cap E) + \mu^*(A\setminus E) \hspace{0.5 cm} (\forall A \subseteq X)$$
But I don't have any idea for doing that.

Do I have to work on different conditions separately? For example; 1. $E = X$, 2. $E = \emptyset$, 3. $E \subset X$ and $E \neq \emptyset$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition $\mu^*$ is $\sigma$-subadditive, and is monotone (see [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure) for instance). Writing $A = (A\cap E) \cup (A\setminus E) $ and applying the sub-additivity of $\mu^*$ we get
$$
\mu^*(A ) \leq \mu^*(A\cap E) + \mu^*(A \setminus E) \leq \mu^*(E) + \mu^*(A) = \mu^*(A),
$$
where the second inequality follows by monotonicity of $\mu^*$.
Hence  $\mu^*(A) = \mu^*(A\cap E) + \mu^*(A \setminus E)$.